# Que nombre lleva esto? y se puede agragar el contenido a una Basedatos?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Que nombre lleva esto y como lo agrego a una web para mysql?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es que quiero crear asi como en los foros un texto Web este puede o no incluir imagenes y link pero no se donde sacar los codigos Fuentes, este pudiera servirme pero lo hare para terceros que no saben crear una web entonces quiero o mejor dicho necesito hacerlo tipo codigos BB.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Juan. No queda muy claro lo que comentas y no hay ningun tipo de implementacion (por que PHP, por ejemplo? Tienes algo de codigo?)

Answer (score 3):

Estos son llamados comúnmente como editores **WYSIWYG** (*What You See Is What You Get*; en español, "lo que ves es lo que obtienes")
Échale un vistazo a estos dos:

- [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/)
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de código para la inserción del Editor HTML WYSIWYG de ***TinyMCE***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Editado con  más información acerca de TinyMCE

Comment: Así está mejor, un simple enlace se puede dejar como comentario pero no como una respuesta